# How to use asyncio properly for a generator function?

Tags: python, io, python-asyncio

I'm reading in several thousand files at once, and for each file I need to perform operations on before yielding rows from each file. To increase performance I thought I could use asyncio to perhaps perform operations on files (and yield rows) whilst waiting for new files to be read in.

However from print statements I can see that all the files are opened and gathered, then each file is iterated over (same as would occur without asyncio).

I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious here which is making my asynchronous attempts, synchronous.

```
import asyncio

async def open_files(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        # do stuff
        print('opening files')
        return x

async def async_generator():
    file_outputs = await asyncio.gather(*[open_files(file) for file in files])

    for file_output in file_ouputs:
        print('using open file')
        for row in file_output:
            # Do stuff to row
            yield row

async def main():
    async for yield_value in async_generator():
        pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
opening files
opening files
.
.
.
using open file
using open file
```

---

### EDIT

Using the code supplied by @user4815162342, I noticed that, although it was 3x quicker, the set of rows yielded from the generator were slightly different than if done without concurrency. I'm unsure as of yet if this is because some yields were missed out from each file, or if the files were somehow re-ordered. So I introduced the following changes to the code from user4815162342 and entered a lock into the `pool.submit()`

I should have mentioned when first asking, the ordering of rows in each file and of the files themselves is required.

```
import concurrent.futures

def open_files(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        # do stuff
        print('opening files')
        return x

def generator():
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    file_output_futures = [pool.submit(open_files, file, lock) for file in files]
    for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(file_output_futures):
        file_output = fut.result()
        print('using open file')
        for row in file_output:
            # Do stuff to row
            yield row

def main():
    for yield_value in generator():
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way my non-concurrent and concurrent approaches yield the same values each time, however I have just lost all the speed gained from using concurrency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious here which is making my asynchronous attempts, synchronous.

There are two issues with your code. The first one is that `asyncio.gather()` by design waits for *all* the futures to complete in parallel, and only then returns their results. So the processing you do in the generator is not interspersed with the IO in `open_files` as was your intention, but only begins after all the calls to `open_files` have returned. To process async calls as they are done, you should be using something like [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed).

The second and more fundamental issue is that, unlike threads which can parallelize synchronous code, asyncio requires everything to be async from the ground up. It's not enough to add `async` to a function like `open_files` to make it async. You need to go through the code and replace any blocking calls, such as calls to IO, with equivalent async primitives. For example, connecting to a network port should be done with [`open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection), and so on. If your async function doesn't await anything, as appears to be the case with `open_files`, it will execute exactly like a regular function and you won't get any benefits of asyncio.

Since you use IO on regular files, and operating systems don't expose portable async interface for regular files, you are unlikely to profit from asyncio. There are libraries like aiofiles that use threads under the hood, but they are as likely to make your code slower than to speed it up because their nice-looking async APIs involve a lot of internal thread synchronization. To speed up your code, you can use a classic thread pool, which Python exposes through the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module. For example (untested):

```
import concurrent.futures

def open_files(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        # do stuff
        print('opening files')
        return x

def generator():
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    file_output_futures = [pool.submit(open_files, file) for file in files]
    for fut in file_output_futures:
        file_output = fut.result()
        print('using open file')
        for row in file_output:
            # Do stuff to row
            yield row

def main():
    for yield_value in generator():
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Code works and super helpful explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: One thing I noticed in the output, which I hadn't thought of before, is that using `concurrent.futures.as_completed`, the `fut` which is operated on will change orders.

The solution I used for this is

`m = multiprocessing.Manager()`,    
`lock = m.lock()`,    
`file_output_futures = [pool.submit(open_files, file, lock) for file in files]`.    
This keeps everything in the correct order but erases the processing speed gained.
Is there a way to keep everything in order without slowing it down? @user4815162342

Comment: @dreadblenks I'm not sure what order you're referring to. Obviously `as_completed` will return the futures in the order in which they complete, which may not be the order in which they submitted. If you need the order to be respected, then you perhaps cannot use parallelism? Also, it's not clear to me why you used `multiprocessing.Manager` (as this code doesn't use multiprocessing at all), or where you placed `m.lock()`. I suggest that you edit the question to specify your requirements in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. Yes I do need the order to be respected for both the files and the rows within the files, so maybe I can't use parallelism...

Comment: @dreadblenks A possible solution occurred to me to keep the order but retain parallelism; please try the edited version of the answer.

Comment: It works! I would have thought that the `as_completed` was an integral part of executing different code whilst waiting for the previous operations to complete...

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @dreadblenks `as_completed` serves a different purpose, and does it correctly. It gives you futures *as they complete*, i.e. you get each completed future as soon as possible. For example, if future 5 completes first, you'll get it first to be able to react to it.